# How can I get share link from Google Drive REST api v3?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, php-curl

After uploading a file to GoogleDrive, I can get an `fileId` from the response, then I pass the `fileId` to the following function:

```php
public function createShareLink($fileId, $accessToken){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL =>  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$fileId.'/permissions',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(['type'=>'anyone', 'role'=>'reader',]),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Authorization:Bearer '.$accessToken,
            'Content-Type:application/json',
        ],
        //In case you're in Windows, sometimes will throw error if not set SSL verification to false
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    ];
    //In case you need a proxy
    //$options[CURLOPT_PROXY] = 'http://127.0.0.1:1087';

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

It did works and it returns a json:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "id": "anyoneWithLink",
 "type": "anyone",
 "role": "reader",
 "allowFileDiscovery": false
}
```

The file in GoogleDrive have indeed become shared status:
[image: shared file in GoogleDrive]

But there's no share link in the response json, so I check the documentation, in [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create#parameters), you can find the `fields` parameter(see the ScreenShot below):
[image: fields parameter]

Click the [partial response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial-response) will redirect you to a page which includes some examples about how you pass values to the `fileds` parameters.

I follow the example pass `webViewLink` as value to `fields` like this:

```
CURLOPT_URL =>  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$fileId.'/permissions?fields=webViewLink',
```

But response an error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid field selection webViewLink",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fields"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid field selection webViewLink"
 }
}
```

I tried `id`:

```
CURLOPT_URL =>  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$fileId.'/permissions?fields=id',
```

The response is:

```
{
 "id": "anyoneWithLink"
}
```

I tried `name`:

```
CURLOPT_URL =>  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$fileId.'/permissions?fields=name',
```

The response is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid field selection name",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fields"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid field selection name"
 }
}
```

I tried `mimeType`:

```
CURLOPT_URL =>  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$fileId.'/permissions?fields=mimeType',
```

The response is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid field selection mimeType",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fields"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid field selection mimeType"
 }
}
```

I really don't know how can this `fields` parameter works, cause I think `webViewLink`, `name` and `mimeType` are correct fields, they all describe in [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations), **anyone did this before?** I'm not gonna use the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) cause its size is too large(>20M).

Comment: Its always a good choice to use the api provided from google, the RAW apis does work but requires lot of efforts from the perspective of coding and exception handling both. I am not sure why >20M size is a problem for you as nowadays storage doesn't matter that much unless you are running your server on an IoT device.

Comment: @SariqShaikh Actually it's not about the storage, it's about the `google-api-php-client` takes up 1/3 of my tool's size(I'm working on a upload tool), becides, the library has many problems, like [this one](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1740#issuecomment-551366849), and it lack of documentation, like I really don't know how can I upload files in multiple chunks by using the google-api-php-client and sometimes the documentation have no `php` examples, like [this one](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing), but i work it all out with GuzzleHttp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirements:

- You want to retrieve `webViewLink` using php.
- You want to achieve this using curl without using googleapis of php.
- You have already been used Drive API.

#### Issue:

- In your case, you are trying to retrieve `webViewLink` from the method of Permissions: create in Drive API. Unfortunately, the method of Permissions: create has no fields of `file`. By this, the fields of `webViewLink`, `name` and `mimeType` cannot be directly retrieved from the method of Permissions: create.
- About `I really don't know how can this fields parameter works, cause I think webViewLink, name and mimeType are correct fields, they all describe in [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations), anyone did this before?`,

  - In this case, please check [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions). You can see the fields parameters at there.

By above sitaution, such error occurs.

#### Workaround 1:

Fortunately, the format of `webViewLink` is the constant. Using this, you can directly retrieve `webViewLink` using the file ID like below.

```
$webViewLink = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/'.$fileId.'/view?usp=drivesdk';
```

#### Workaround 2:

If you want to retrieve `webViewLink` using API, how about using the method of Files: get in Drive API? The sample script is as follows.

##### Sample script:

```
function getWebViewLink($fileId, $accessToken){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL =>  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$fileId.'?fields=webViewLink',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Authorization:Bearer '.$accessToken],
    ];
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, after reading your answer, I'm now understand why `webViewLink`, `name` and `mimeType` cannot be retrieved from the method of Permissions: `create` and I think workaround 1 is the best solution, workaround 2 will need one more request of api, it means takes more time to get the webViewLink, so I will use workaround 1, thank you again, I really appreciate you.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to get the **real** image url of the `webViewLink `, the one using this domain "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com", you can see it in the HTML element, because only this url can embed into markdown document.

Comment: @Bruce Xie Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For example, how about posting it as new question? By this, a lot of users can see your question and it will lead to the solution of your new question. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your new question soon.

Comment: It's ok, I will post a new question, thank you for your answer again, it's really helpful.